# Pyspark calculate column with lag

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a Balance column in the following spark df where for each company it would take the first value from "Check" column and each following row would be calculated as previous row * (1+interest). How can I achieve that?

```
+----------+--------+------------+---------+
|      Date|interest|Check       |  Company|
+----------+--------+------------+---------+
|2023-12-31|       7|         704|Company A|
|2024-12-31|       7|         704|Company A|
|2025-12-31|       7|         704|Company A|
|2026-12-31|       7|         704|Company A|
|2023-12-31|       7|         704|Company B|
|2024-12-31|       7|         704|Company B|
|2025-12-31|       7|         704|Company B|
|2026-12-31|       7|         704|Company B|
|2023-12-31|       7|         704|Company C|
|2024-12-31|       7|         704|Company C|
|2025-12-31|       7|         704|Company C|
|2026-12-31|       7|         704|Company C|
+----------+--------+------------+---------+
```

Expected output:

```
+----------+--------+------------+---------+------------------+
|      Date|interest|Check       |  Company|     Balance      |
+----------+--------+------------+---------+------------------+
|2023-12-31|       7|         704|Company A|               704|
|2024-12-31|       7|         704|Company A|  1507.680000000000|
|2025-12-31|       7|         704|Company A|  2321.797600000000|
|2026-12-31|       7|         704|Company A|  3306.447232000000|
|2023-12-31|       7|         704|Company B|               704|
|2024-12-31|       7|         704|Company B|  1507.680000000000|
|2025-12-31|       7|         704|Company B|  2321.797600000000|
|2026-12-31|       7|         704|Company B|  3306.447232000000|
|2023-12-31|       7|         704|Company C|               704|
|2024-12-31|       7|         704|Company C|  1507.680000000000|
|2025-12-31|       7|         704|Company C|  2321.797600000000|
|2026-12-31|       7|         704|Company C|  3306.447232000000|
+----------+--------+------------+---------+------------------+
```

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Comment: Balance column was the expected output. I have edited now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the lag function like

`from pyspark.sql.window import Window`

`df.withColumn("Balance", col("Check"))`

`windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("Company").orderBy("Date")`

`from pyspark.sql.functions import lag`

`df.withColumn("lag",lag("Balance", 1).over(windowSpec))`

`df.withColumn("balance", col("lag") * (1 + interest_variable)`

The lag function expects a value in balance to be populated so I have copied the check value over to balance which gets overwritten except for the first entry which is used to initialise the interest accrual process

Comment: I think the balance column is the one to be calculated, this lag can't be used.

Comment: I tried some variations of your code but dont think this approach works.